# How to know the count of rows in each cluster with dbscan?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The csv data likes this:

```
device_id,upload_time,latitude,longitude,mileage,other_vals,speed,upload_time_1
A0001,2020-08-05 05:10:05+00:00,23.140366,114.18685,0.0,,0,202008
A0001,2020-08-05 05:10:33+00:00,22.994716,114.2998,0.0,,0,202008
A0001,2020-08-05 05:20:55+00:00,22.994716,114.2998,0.0,,3.8,202008
A0001,2020-08-05 05:24:02+00:00,22.994916,114.299683,0.0,,2.1,202008
A0001,2020-08-05 05:24:30+00:00,22.99545,114.2998,0.0,,6.5,202008
A0001,2020-08-05 05:29:30+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0.0,,3.4,202008
A0001,2020-08-05 05:34:30+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0.0,,3.4,202008
A0001,2020-08-05 05:39:30+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0.0,,3.4,202008
A0001,2020-08-05 05:44:30+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0.0,,3.4,202008
A0001,2020-08-05 05:44:53+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0.0,,3.4,202008
A0001,2020-08-05 05:45:40+00:00,22.995433,114.299766,0.0,,5.8,202008
```

I use the latitude and longitude data in csv to generate dbscan clustering images,the color of each cluster is different.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def draw_with_dbscan(para_csv_path_name,para_csv_name,para_save_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(para_csv_path_name, encoding='utf-8', parse_dates=[1], low_memory=False)
    X = df[['latitude', 'longitude']]
    X = X.drop_duplicates()
    kms_per_rad = 6371.0088  # mean radius of the earth
    epsilon = 1.5 / kms_per_rad  # The maximum distance between two samples for one to be considered as in the neighborhood of the other. This is not a maximum bound on the distances of points within a cluster. This is the most important DBSCAN parameter to choose appropriately for your data set and distance function. default=0.5
    dbsc = (DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=1, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(X)))
    fac_cluster_labels = dbsc.labels_
    # get the number of clusters
    num_clusters = len(set(dbsc.labels_))
    # turn the clusters into a pandas series,where each element is a cluster of points
    dbsc_clusters = pd.Series([X[fac_cluster_labels == n] for n in range(num_clusters)])
    # get centroid of each cluster
    fac_centroids = dbsc_clusters.map(get_centroid)
    # unzip the list of centroid points (lat, lon) tuples into separate lat and lon lists
    cent_lats, cent_lons = zip(*fac_centroids)
    # from these lats/lons create a new df of one representative point for eac cluster
    centroids_pd = pd.DataFrame({'longitude': cent_lons, 'latitude': cent_lats})
    # Plot the faciity clusters and cluster centroid
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[20, 10])
    facility_scatter = ax.scatter(X['longitude'], X['latitude'], c=fac_cluster_labels,
                                  edgecolor='None', alpha=0.7, s=120)
    centroid_scatter = ax.scatter(centroids_pd['longitude'], centroids_pd['latitude'], marker='x', linewidths=2,
                                  c='k', s=50)
    ax.set_title('Facility Clusters & Facility Centroid', fontsize=30)
    ax.set_xlabel('Longitude', fontsize=24)
    ax.set_ylabel('Latitude', fontsize=24)
    ax.legend([facility_scatter, centroid_scatter], ['Facilities', 'Facility Cluster Centroid'], loc='upper right',
              fontsize=20)
    # plt.show()
    plt.savefig(para_save_path + para_csv_name.split('.')[0] + '.png')
    plt.close()


def get_centroid(cluster):
    """calculate the centroid of a cluster of geographic coordinate points
    Args:
      cluster coordinates, nx2 array-like (array, list of lists, etc)
      n is the number of points(latitude, longitude)in the cluster.
    Return:
      geometry centroid of the cluster

    """
    cluster_ary = np.asarray(cluster)
    centroid = cluster_ary.mean(axis=0)
    return centroid



if __name__ == '__main__':
    csvlName=r'E:/mydata/test.csv'
    item='test.csv'
    abnormal_dbscan_device_img_dir=r'E:/result/'
    draw_with_dbscan(csvlName, item, abnormal_dbscan_device_img_dir)
```

The generated image is like this:
[image]

But how to know the count of rows about latitude and longitude data in each cluster with dbscan?

Comment: Can you think please about [reprex] relevant to your title with desired output?

Comment: I have modified my code.

Comment: Still not clear what problem you have but you may try `values, counts = np.unique(fac_cluster_labels,return_counts=True); {k:v for k,v in zip(values,counts)}`

Comment: For example, a csv has 100 rows of latitude and longitude data, which is divided into 4 clusters. The purple cluster has 10 rows of data, the blue cluster has 20 rows of data, the yellow cluster has 30 rows of data, and the green cluster has 40 rows. data, I want to know how many rows of data each cluster has.

Comment: Did you try the code I suggested above?

Comment: Yes,I used your code,the result is right,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to try:

```
values = np.unique(fac_cluster_labels,return_counts=True)
{k:v for k,v in zip(*values)}
```

Comment: Yes,this is what I want.